# Memory Management when to autorelease a return value

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have been searching through the web and reading many posts, but none has yet to explain me how this exactly works. I know that the convention says that any method must return an autoreleased object (except for alloc, new, copy and mutableCopy) so something like this is fine:

```
-(MyClass*)findRandomName { return [[[MyClass alloc] initWithString:@"Something"] autorelease]; }
```

My question is, should I also call autorelease on the return value if I use a convenience method, or something similar? like here:

```
-(MyClass*)findRandomName { return [[MyClass startFromString:@"Something"] autorelease]; }
```

And why, or why not ? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where's the call to 'alloc' in the first line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is incorrect as it should call `[MyClass alloc]` before calling `initWithString`, e.g.:

```
-(MyClass*)findRandomName { 
    return [[[MyClass alloc] initWithString:@"Something"] autorelease]; 
}
```

In the second example you should ***not*** `autorelease` the object.  The `startFromString` method should already `autorelease` the object and if you `autorelease` it again you will over release the object.

In the second example the `findRandomName` method does not take ownership of the object (because the method it calls does not contain `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` in the name) so it should not `release` the object.

Your statement that "the convention says that any method must return an autoreleased object (except for init, new and copy)" is not quite correct.  The [memory management policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) says:

> **You own any object you create**
>
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”,
>   “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or
>   mutableCopy).

Comment: If you think this answers your question don't forget to accept it.

Comment: I sure will, when the timer lets me ;)